# Why my if statement gives false negatives?

Tags: python, if-statement, jupyter-notebook

I want to iterate over a list of files in Python 3. They are CSV files containing matrices. I want to do the same with all of them so I wanted to create a list with their names, remove all other files in the folder from the list and do my transformation with the relevants.

My target files all end with "2m.csv" (e.g.: 14-17_CCK_all_2m.csv) and my results at the end of the process will end with "1m.csv". Still when I run the following script in Jupyter notebook, the result contains some files ending with "1m.csv" (they remained there from an earlier cycle of the development)

```
import os
myfiles = os.listdir()

for item in myfiles:
    if item[-6:] != "2m.csv":
        myfiles.remove(item)
```

Interestingly, if I test one of the false negatives in a separate lines, I get a True answer, so the if statement should have eliminated it from my list in the script above - which it did with some of them, but not with some others:

```
myfiles[1][-6:] != "2m.csv"
>>> True
```

All the files in question have very similar name structure. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unsure this is the cause, but in other languages, modifying a list that you're iterating over is either disallowed or can produce inaccurate results. You could try copying the items to a second list, and iterate over one of them while modifying the other.

Comment: Have you looked at the exact output of one of these false positives? Can you post a filename where the if check consistently behaves unexpectedly?

Comment: modifying a collection/list --  iterating it is always likely to produce this sort of discrepancy. If you add a `print` statement before your `if` statement, you'll probably see that `"2m.csv"` doesn't print. THe reason being that as you're removing from the list, the list is re-indexed, and the iteration effectively skips over the item.

Comment: `myfiles = [item for item in myfiles if item[-6:] == '2m.csv']` is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Better use list comprehensions:

```
myfiles = [x for x in os.listdir() if x[-6:] == '2m.csv']
```

And I prefer to use `endswith()` method, not slices:

```
myfiles = [x for x in os.listdir() if x.endswith('2m.csv')]
```

Comment: the first command in your answer has a bug. Should be "==", otherwise it will be a collection of not 2m.csv files ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems in your `for` loop. You are iterating through and modify `myfiles` at the same time.

The solution is to filter out wrong file names inline.

```
import os
myfiles = [ item for item in os.listdir() if item[-6:] == "2m.cvs" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

To `filter` the list in Python, like you would want, don't use `for` loop to iterate over it. It's better to use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

So it would look like this:

```
import os
myfiles = [f for f in os.listdir() if f[-6:] == "2m.csv"]
```

It's more clean, its usually faster on benchmarks, and it does the job you want it to do (and it's also a lot cleaner than `map/filter` - but that's my subjective opinion)

Answer (score 0):

modifying a collection/list --  iterating it is always likely to produce this sort of discrepancy. If you add a `print` statement before your `if` statement, you'll probably see that `"2m.csv"` doesn't print. THe reason being that as you're removing from the list, the list is re-indexed, and the iteration effectively skips over the item.

The solution as given in the linked duplicate is to use list comprehension:

```
myfiles = [item for item in myfiles if item[-6:] == "2m.csv"]
```

Alternatively, if you prefer to use a `for` loop, you need to iterate backwards, so that the removal of items (and subsequent re-indexing) doesn't affect the remaining items.

```
for i in range(len(myfiles)-1,-1,-1):
    if myfiles[i][-6:] != "2m.csv":
        myfiles.remove(i)
```

But the list comprehension method would be more concise and more pythonic.